# RequestHandler is not invoked in Netty server

Tags: java, netty

I am working on Netty Http server. I have handlers created and registered. But I do not see the request hitting the handler

Here is the main class

```
public class NettyServer {

    private int port;

    private NettyServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } else {
            port = 8080;
        }
        new NettyServer(port).run();
    }

    private void run() throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpMessageHandler(),new CalculatorOperationHandler());
                }
            }).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128).childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync();
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

**HttpMessageHandler.java**

```
public class HttpMessageHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {

    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello");
        String uri = msg.uri();
        HttpMethod httpMethod = msg.method();
        HttpHeaders headers = msg.headers();

        if (HttpMethod.GET == httpMethod) {

            String[] uriComponents = uri.split("[?]");
            String endpoint = uriComponents[0];
            String[] queryParams = uriComponents[1].split("&");

            if ("/calculate".equalsIgnoreCase(endpoint)) {

                String[] firstQueryParam = queryParams[0].split("=");
                String[] secondQueryParam = queryParams[1].split("=");

                Integer a = Integer.valueOf(firstQueryParam[1]);
                Integer b = Integer.valueOf(secondQueryParam[1]);
                String operator = headers.get("operator");

                Operation operation = new Operation(a, b, operator);
                ctx.fireChannelRead(operation);
            }
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("HTTP method not supported");
        }

    }
}
```

I do not see "hello" printed in console when I invoke `localhost:8080/calculate?a=1&b=2`

what is wrong here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190947/discussion-on-question-by-brain-storm-requesthandler-is-not-invoked-in-netty-ser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is caused by missing handlers in your pipeline.

At your moment, you only have 2 handlers in your pipeline:

- `HttpMessageHandler`, that handles `FullHttpRequest` objects
- `CalculatorOperationHandler`, that handles `Operation` objects

When data from the browser comes in, it comes in as a `ByteBuf` object, but you don't handle this object!

To convert from a `ByteBuf` to a `FullHttpRequest`, you need to add other handlers in your pipeline that can do this.

The first handler you need is `HttpServerCodec`, this class converts `ByteBuf` objects into objects that are parts of an HTTP exchange, like headers, trailing headers an request bodies.

Then you need to add a `HttpObjectAggregator`, that combines the above objects into a `FullHttpRequest`, so you only have to deal with 1 object.

```
ch.pipeline().addLast(
    new HttpServerCodec(),
    new HttpObjectAggregator(65536), // Handle POST/PUT requests up 64KB
    new HttpMessageHandler(),
    new CalculatorOperationHandler()
);
```

You could also add a `new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO)` if you want to see the traffic between any layer.

Comment: why is HttpServerCodec and HttpObjectAggregator not used here then https://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/http/snoop/package-summary.html

Comment: HttpServerCodec automatically adds HttpRequestEncoder and HttpRequestDecoder, and since that example does not deal with instances of HttpFullRequest, they don't need the aggregator

Comment: so are you saying if I don't add HttpServerCodec, I need to have a custom Encoder and decoder added? In other words, if I added ResponseEncoder and RequestDecoder, I don't need HttpServerCodec? btw, do you mean HttpResponseEncoder instead of HttpRequestEncoder ?

Comment: The [docs of `HttpServerCodec`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpServerCodec.html) say that is A combination of `HttpRequestDecoder` and `HttpResponseEncoder`, so it basically replaces them.

Comment: I have another question similar to this. but I cannot find a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462284/channelread-method-is-not-getting-invoked-when-a-request-is-made-for-netty-serve