# ChannelRead method is not getting invoked when a request is made for netty server

Tags: netty

I am implementing a netty server that accepts http request and do some business logic
Basically, I accept GET request on localhost/hello and sysout `uri is hello`

when I run the server, I do not see any of sysouts in CustomRequestHandler#channelRead0 method.
I kept the debugger on and I see the channelRead0 method is not getting invoked.
I cannot figure out what the problem is

I am using Netty 4.1.30.Final version

```
public class HttpServer {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

        InetSocketAddress tcpSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(8080);

        System.out.println("Starting http server at " + tcpSocketAddress.getPort());
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {

        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
                .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                .childHandler(new MyChannelInitializer())
                .childOption(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);


        ChannelFuture serverChannelFuture = bootstrap.bind(tcpSocketAddress).sync();
        System.out.println("open the browser");
        serverChannelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
             bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
             workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}


public class MyChannelIntializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
        p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
        //p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
        p.addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
        p.addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());
        p.addLast(new CustomRequestHandler());
    }
}

public class CustomRequestHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object httpObject) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
        if (httpObject instanceof HttpRequest) {
            HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) httpObject;
            System.out.println("uri is " + request.getUri());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use :

```
                .childOption(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
```

This means once a channel is accepted it will not process any incoming data until you call `ctx.read()` every time you want to process more inbound data.

So your options are either to remove this line or override `channelActive(...)` as well in your `CustomRequestHandler` and call `ctx.read()` there. This will ensure you will try to read some inbound data. That said you will need to call `ctx.read()` again when you want to process more data.

Comment: for every request, a new pipeline is created?

Comment: no not for every request but for each Channel (connection). Please open another stack overflow question if you have other questions.

Comment: just opened one..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468201/netty-channelread-method-is-never-invoked-on-httpproxybackendhandler